# two decimal places for decimal/money field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have a table with money field in my database. I have created entity and created decimal property for that money field. When the value of that field is displayed on My MVC3 view, It has four zeros 0000 after decimal like this : 5489.0000. I want to show only two 00 or decimal places. How can I fix it. Why it is showing four decimal places even I declared property as decimal.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The SQL Server `money` datatype internally is a 64-bit integer with an implied scale of 4 decimal places. To quote Books Online, it is accurate "to ten-thousandsth of a currency unit." It is, the rough equivalent of a `decimal(19,4)`.

The reason for the scale of 4 rather than 2 is to maintain precision in the results of arithmetic. Your ordinary currency value has a scale of 2 (e.g. $3.27) Multiplication or division of two numbers scaled to 2 decimal places gives a results that is precise to 4 decimal places: 9.23 divided by 3.27 yields a result of 2.82262996941896 (approximately). You can carry the result to whatever *accuracy* (number of decimal places) you desire. However, the result is only *precise* to 4 decimal places (2.8226) as the original values were only precise to 2 decimal places. That measurement is precise to within 1/2 of the smallest unit specified (+/- 0.005).

But I digress.

As a result of a SQL Server `money` value having an implied scale of 4, ADO.Net converts the value to a System.Decimal with a scale of 4. And since System.Decimal tracks scale, when you convert it to string, you get 4 decimal places.

To get fewer, you can

- Round it before conversion, using the appropriate `Decimal.Round()` overload, or
- Format it as desired (eg. `(3.27M).ToString("0.00") ;`.

Hope this helps.

This program:

```
namespace Sandbox
{
  using System ;
  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      decimal pi     = (decimal) Math.PI ;
      string  piText = pi.ToString("0.00");
      Console.WriteLine("PI to 2 decimal places is {0} one way, and {1:0.00} another" , piText , pi ) ;
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Produces what you'd expect:

```
PI to 2 decimal places is 3.14 one way, and 3.14 another
```

Cheers,

N.

Comment: I am using decimal? and ToString("0:00) can not be used with it

Comment: Somebody should tell that to the .Net runtime. See example in my original answer.

Comment: Formating dores not work in DevExpress components. Which are full of bugs like this BTW.

Answer (score 6):

You have to format the string.

One thing you can do if it money you want to display is:

```
static void Main () 
{
    decimal x = 0.999m;
    decimal y = 9999999999999999999999999999m;
    Console.WriteLine("My amount = {0:C}", x);
    Console.WriteLine("Your amount = {0:C}", y);
}
```

}

OUTPUT:
Output

My amount = $1.00
Your amount = $9,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999,999.00

the {0:C} is the currency Format

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Nico: I don't want to put $ with amount. How can I modify string.format("{0:C}",amount) ?

Comment: the you could say decimal dec = 5489.0000M;

dec.ToString("0.00");

Answer (score 3):

Here is everything you need to know about formatting strings.

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it worked:

```
YourDecField.ToString("N")
```