# C# Decimal to SQL Server Money

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, currency

I have a SQL Server SPROC that takes a money paramater.

I'm passing in a C# decimal to this SPROC

How do I pass in the decimal from C# to the money type in the SPROC in such a way that I wont loose any values after the point

Comment: how do you passing decimal value to sproc? Parameter with type Money?

Comment: here is the info you seek http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075067/two-decimal-places-for-decimal-money-field

Comment: Reniuz yes param with type money

Comment: "Won't lose any values after the point" - if you have any values after the 4th, you're doomed, since money has a fixed scale of 4.

Answer (score 4):

Just initialize the Parameter with a new `SqlMoney(decimal)` constructor.

`SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("@Money", SqlDbType.Money);`

See the [SQLMoney Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlmoney.sqlmoney%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this : [What is the best data type to use for money in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693372/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-c)

Or you can look into the `.Parse` overrides. I know theres a lot of format and currency is one of them.